# How do I get VS to properly "see" code I have in App_Code folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a class located in App_Code that can't be seen by my ASPX pages.

Anyone know why this could be?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a web application project, or a web site project?

Ensure that the namespace is respected, either by `using` or fully qualified.

Consider renaming the directory to something else... perhaps "Helpers" or something descriptive.